# .KEY and .CSR files but no .CRT file

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate, csr

I'm working migrating a Java app to NodeJS, they are using SSL and they gave me some files related with this:

```
www.domain.com.key
www.domain.com.csr
```

But I'm not an expert on this topic, and I'm trying to setting up the SSL certificate with Express but it seems a **.CRT** file is also required.

I asked them, but they told me that **.CRT** is actually inside of the **.CSR** file.

Not sure what should I do to make it work, I've been reading and doing lots of things without success, any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .key file is probably your PRIVATE key

The .csr file is a CERTIFICATE REQUEST probably signed with your private key

What you need is probably a .crt : a certificate corresponding to your csr signed by a certificate authority (or self signed, depending what you want to accomplish)

node (like another web server) is supposed to ask you 3 thing :
- your private key
- the certificate
- the certificate chain, eventually, depending of the certificate

What you can do is open with a text editor the different files, and see if you see the certificate inside:

you should see things like -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- or -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- or -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- , that will told you the exact content of the files.